# Form tag is not rendering only for first item asp.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image]

```
@model IEnumerable<TransferListItemMV>

@if (Model != null && Model.Count()>0)
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 @(i%3==0?"border":string.Empty)">
            <!-- CONTAINER-->
            @Html.Partial("_TransferListItem", ((List<TransferListItemMV>)Model)[i])
            <!-- END OF CONTAINER-->
         </div>
         if (i%3==2)
         {
             <div class="clearfix"></div><br />
         }
    }
    <div class="offset-2"><hr class="featurette-divider3"></div>
}
```

_TransferListItem is

```
@model  TransferListItemMV
<div class="carscontainer">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddBookServiceTransfer", "Payment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm" + Model.Id.ToString() }))
{
        <div class="center">
            <img src=@Model.Image alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="hpadding20">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign right lblue cpointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#transfer@(Model.Id)"></span>

            <div id="transfer@(Model.Id)" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Detailed Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @(new HtmlString(Model.Description))
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="size14 bold dark">@Model.ShortDescription</span><br />
            <span class="size13 grey">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dark bold" valign="top">From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>@Model.From</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dark bold" valign="top">To:</td>
                        <td>@Model.To</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dark bold" valign="top">On:</td>
                        <td>@Model.On</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="purchasecontainer">
            <span class="size18 bold green mt5">€@(Math.Round(Model.Price, 2))</span><br />
            <span class="size12 mt-3 grey">&nbsp;</span>
            <button class="bookbtn right margtop-20" type="submit">Book</button>
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.AvailToken)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.TransferType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.DateFrom)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.TransferInfo.Code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.TransferInfo.Type)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.TransferInfo.VehicleType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.ContractList.ContractList[0].Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.ContractList.ContractList[0].IncomingOffice)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.PickupLocation.Code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.DestinationLocation.Code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.DestinationLocation.TransferZone.Code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.Paxes.AdultCount)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.Paxes.ChildCount)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.ArrivalTransferInfo.ArrivalInfo.Code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.ArrivalTransferInfo.ArrivalInfo.DateTime)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.ArrivalTransferInfo.ArrivalInfo.Code)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.XMLServiceTransfer.ArrivalTransferInfo.ArrivalInfo.DateTime)
    }
</div>
```

When rendering this in browser only first item has not form tag in ASP.MVC

What is the problem?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have expanded the `<div class="classcontainer">_</div>` as you did for the second item. So just click on the `▶` arrow in front of the div to expand it and see the `<form>` tag that's inside, the same way as you did for the second div.

Comment: I did it. But there is no  form tag.